# Ractive.js continue and break loops

Tags: javascript, loops, mustache, continue, ractivejs

I have a list which I am iterating through:

```
<ul>
    {{#list}}
    <li>{{this.value}}</li>
    {{/list}}
</ul>
```

How would I continue the loop if {{this.hidden}} is true?

I would like to do something like this:

```
{[#if this.hidden]} {[continue]} {[/if]}
```

Is this possible with RactiveJS?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a `break` or `continue` statement (or something equivalent) in Ractive mustaches, at least according to their docs. You can still achieve the same effect though.

Instead of `continue` based on some condition, just handle the opposite condition.

```
{[#if !this.hidden]} {[do whatever...]} {[/if]}
```

Instead of `break`ing the loop, filter the array prior to binding.

```
var listModified = [];
for (var i=0; i < ractive.get("list").length; i++) {
    if (/* some condition */)
        break;
    listModified.push(ractive.get("list")[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a computed property that returns an array which omits those that are hidden. Assuming the list is a list of objects:

Add this to your configuration:

```
computed: {
  listWithoutHidden: function(){
    return this.get('list').filter(function(item){
      return !item.hidden;
    });
  }
}
```

And update the template

```
<ul>
    {{#listWithoutHidden}}
    <li>{{this.value}}</li>
    {{/list}}
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer is the correct way of thinking. You need to do your logic on your data **before** sending it to mustaches.